# DART avast_ye_pirates pub build

Tags: dart

I was going through the "Avast, Ye Pirates" tutorial and have reached [**Step 7: Build the app and run as Javascript**](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/#step-seven)
The build is successful (except I get "Built 46 files!" instead of "Built 45 files!" as shown on the tutorial web page).
Then I go to folder `build/6-piratebadge`, right click on `piratebadge.html`, <kbd>Run as Javascript</kbd>.

In the Progress tab, an error message:

> Launching piratebadge.html(5) (Finished at 1:49pm)
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Launching piratebadge.html(5)".

The Output tab:

> --- Feb 5, 2014 1:49:09 PM Running dart2js... ---

I tried this several times, and the number (5) was on my last attempt.

When I try this same step from any other build folder, I get the same error.
When I try this from any of the "web/<1,2,3,4,5,6>" the page displays in the regular Chrome browser and works.

I am running this on Windows 7.

Anyone else with the same problem or insight into the cause?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions in the tutorial say:

> Right click the piratebadge.html file and choose Run as JavaScript from the menu. 
>   Copy the URL and run the app in **Firefox or Safari**.

In the Dart Editor you can just righ-click the file you want to run (any build/ folder piratebadge.html in this case), select **Copy the path**, then paste the path into your browser's address bar (for me it works only in Firefox, and does not work in Safari) and hit enter. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `build/6-piratebadge` folder, does it contain `piratebadge.dart` file ? If no, then copy it from the `web` folder, paste it in the corresponding build folder then **Run As JavaScript**.

In my case, the build output was "Built 40 files!", missing the .dart files. Seems like it is a bug in Pub Build command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded.
I attended the DART meetup on 02/23/2014.
On the evening before, on opening the DART editor, there was a new release, which updated my install.
I deleted and redid the Project during the meetup.

- I still got the "46 files" message.
- I did not get the error.

I guess this can be closed.

Comment: I guess the problem was solved by the dart editor update. As it is not relevant any more maybe you should remove it. That way the google crawler won't index it.